# Jemdoc output is faulty

Tags: html, css, jemdoc

I'm just chasing the instructions [here](http://iancassidy.com/jemdoc4win.html) to compile a simple `jemdoc`-generated website (where `jemdoc.css` is right next to it at the same folder).

My machine is running Windows 10, and the python version is 2.7. I am exactly using the sample `index.jemdoc`, which is the official example of the `jemdoc` as follows:

```
# jemdoc: menu{MENU}{example.html}
= jemdoc -- example page
[https://jemnz.com/ Jacob Mattingley] ([www@jemnz.com])
If the first line of the file starts with # jemdoc, special functions like menus will be used.


If the first line of the file starts with +\# jemdoc+, special functions like [menu.html menus] will be used.
Example
Here are some text features. I could link somewhere or insert a raw link to another page like download.html. I could use monospace, too.


== Example
Here are some *text* /features/. I could [http://cvxmod.net/ link somewhere] or insert a raw link to another page like [download.html]. I could use +monospace+, too.
I could write special characters like h (\) in front of those characters. Or automatically detect an email address.


I could write special characters like \#, \$ and \+ by just using a backslash (\\) in front of those characters. Or automatically detect an [www@jemnz.com email address].
Save the file as index.jemdoc, say, and simply call jemdoc index (after downloading jemdoc, of course).

 ~~~
Save the file as +index.jemdoc+, say, and simply call +jemdoc index+ (after [download.html downloading jemdoc], of course).
~~~
Next bit, next heading level two
Getting into level three now

== Next bit, next heading level two
=== Getting into level three now
Why not use a list

to explain the way you do lists?
to demonstrate how a line
break might work?

Why not use a list 
- to explain the way you do lists?
- to demonstrate how a line\n break might work?
Or perhaps a

Multilevel
Numbered list
Is more
Useful?

Or perhaps a 
. Multilevel
  .. Numbered list
  .. Is more
. Useful?
Definition
lists, especially when there are many definitions
Can be useful
for explaining things


: {Definition} lists, especially when there are many definitions 
: {Can be useful} for explaining things
Finally, a few more blocks
This ‘section’ features “smart quotes”.


== Finally, a few more blocks
This `section' features "smart quotes".
Simple block
This is a simple text block, with a title. Notice how the previous line has only one set of braces ({}).

 ~~~
{Simple block}
This is a simple text block, with a title. Notice how the previous line has only one set of braces (\{\}).
~~~
Interactive Python listing
>>> print 'Interactive Python code.'
'Interactive Python code.'

 ~~~
{Interactive Python listing}{pyint}
>>> print 'Interactive Python code.'
'Interactive Python code.'
~~~
 Plain code block with no title.

 ~~~
{}{}
Plain code block with no title.
~~~
You might need 2–3 different-sized dashes — they can be useful. Now we're done!


You might need 2--3 different-sized dashes---they can be useful. Now we're done!
```

After the compilation, the generated `index.html` file is very weird:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<meta name="generator" content="jemdoc, see http://jemdoc.jaboc.net/" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jemdoc.css" type="text/css" />
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="layout-content">
<p>ے‏

 =   j e m d o c   - -   e x a m p l e   p a g e 

 <a href=" h t t p s : / / j e m n z . c o m / "> J a c o b   M a t t i n g l e y </a>   ( <a href="mailto: w w w @ j e m n z . c o m "> w w w @ j e m n z . c o m </a> ) 

 I f   t h e   f i r s t   l i n e   o f   t h e   f i l e   s t a r t s   w i t h   





 I f   t h e   f i r s t   l i n e   o f   t h e   f i l e   s t a r t s   w i t h   <tt>  

 E x a m p l e 

 H e r e   a r e   s o m e   t e x t   f e a t u r e s .   I   c o u l d   l i n k   s o m e w h e r e   o r   i n s e r t   a   r a w   l i n k   t o   a n o t h e r   p a g e   l i k e   d o w n l o a d . h t m l .   I   c o u l d   u s e   m o n o s p a c e ,   t o o . 





 = =   E x a m p l e 

 H e r e   a r e   s o m e   <b> t e x t </b>   <i> f e a t u r e s </i> .   I   c o u l d   <a href=" h t t p : / / c v x m o d . n e t / "> l i n k   s o m e w h e r e </a>   o r   i n s e r t   a   r a w   l i n k   t o   a n o t h e r   p a g e   l i k e   <a href=" d o w n l o a d . h t m l "> d o w n l o a d . h t m l </a> .   I   c o u l d   u s e   </tt> m o n o s p a c e <tt> ,   t o o . 

 I   c o u l d   w r i t e   s p e c i a l   c h a r a c t e r s   l i k e   h   (  )   i n   f r o n t   o f   t h o s e   c h a r a c t e r s .   O r   a u t o m a t i c a l l y   d e t e c t   a n   e m a i l   a d d r e s s . 





 I   c o u l d   w r i t e   s p e c i a l   c h a r a c t e r s   l i k e    

 S a v e   t h e   f i l e   a s   i n d e x . j e m d o c ,   s a y ,   a n d   s i m p l y   c a l l   j e m d o c   i n d e x   ( a f t e r   d o w n l o a d i n g   j e m d o c ,   o f   c o u r s e ) . 



   &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 

 S a v e   t h e   f i l e   a s   </tt> i n d e x . j e m d o c <tt> ,   s a y ,   a n d   s i m p l y   c a l l   </tt> j e m d o c   i n d e x +   ( a f t e r   <a href=" d o w n l o a d . h t m l "> d o w n l o a d i n g   j e m d o c </a> ,   o f   c o u r s e ) . 

 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 

 N e x t   b i t ,   n e x t   h e a d i n g   l e v e l   t w o 

 G e t t i n g   i n t o   l e v e l   t h r e e   n o w 



 = =   N e x t   b i t ,   n e x t   h e a d i n g   l e v e l   t w o 

 = = =   G e t t i n g   i n t o   l e v e l   t h r e e   n o w 

 W h y   n o t   u s e   a   l i s t 



 t o   e x p l a i n   t h e   w a y   y o u   d o   l i s t s ? 

 t o   d e m o n s t r a t e   h o w   a   l i n e 

 b r e a k   m i g h t   w o r k ? 



 W h y   n o t   u s e   a   l i s t   

 -   t o   e x p l a i n   t h e   w a y   y o u   d o   l i s t s ? 

 -   t o   d e m o n s t r a t e   h o w   a   l i n e  n   b r e a k   m i g h t   w o r k ? 

 O r   p e r h a p s   a 



 M u l t i l e v e l 

 N u m b e r e d   l i s t 

 I s   m o r e 

 U s e f u l ? 



 O r   p e r h a p s   a   

 .   M u l t i l e v e l 

     . .   N u m b e r e d   l i s t 

     . .   I s   m o r e 

 .   U s e f u l ? 

 D e f i n i t i o n 

 l i s t s ,   e s p e c i a l l y   w h e n   t h e r e   a r e   m a n y   d e f i n i t i o n s 

 C a n   b e   u s e f u l 

 f o r   e x p l a i n i n g   t h i n g s 





 :   { D e f i n i t i o n }   l i s t s ,   e s p e c i a l l y   w h e n   t h e r e   a r e   m a n y   d e f i n i t i o n s   

 :   { C a n   b e   u s e f u l }   f o r   e x p l a i n i n g   t h i n g s 

 F i n a l l y ,   a   f e w   m o r e   b l o c k s 

 T h i s    s e c t i o n    f e a t u r e s    s m a r t   q u o t e s  . 





 = =   F i n a l l y ,   a   f e w   m o r e   b l o c k s 

 T h i s   &lsquo; s e c t i o n &rsquo;   f e a t u r e s   &ldquo; s m a r t   q u o t e s &rdquo; . 

 S i m p l e   b l o c k 

 T h i s   i s   a   s i m p l e   t e x t   b l o c k ,   w i t h   a   t i t l e .   N o t i c e   h o w   t h e   p r e v i o u s   l i n e   h a s   o n l y   o n e   s e t   o f   b r a c e s   ( { } ) . 



   &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 

 { S i m p l e   b l o c k } 

 T h i s   i s   a   s i m p l e   t e x t   b l o c k ,   w i t h   a   t i t l e .   N o t i c e   h o w   t h e   p r e v i o u s   l i n e   h a s   o n l y   o n e   s e t   o f   b r a c e s   (  {  } ) . 

 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 

 I n t e r a c t i v e   P y t h o n   l i s t i n g 

 &gt; &gt; &gt;   p r i n t   &rsquo; I n t e r a c t i v e   P y t h o n   c o d e . &rsquo; 

 &rsquo; I n t e r a c t i v e   P y t h o n   c o d e . &rsquo; 



   &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 

 { I n t e r a c t i v e   P y t h o n   l i s t i n g } { p y i n t } 

 &gt; &gt; &gt;   p r i n t   &rsquo; I n t e r a c t i v e   P y t h o n   c o d e . &rsquo; 

 &rsquo; I n t e r a c t i v e   P y t h o n   c o d e . &rsquo; 

 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 

   P l a i n   c o d e   b l o c k   w i t h   n o   t i t l e . 



   &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 

 { } { } 

 P l a i n   c o d e   b l o c k   w i t h   n o   t i t l e . 

 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 

 Y o u   m i g h t   n e e d   2  3   d i f f e r e n t - s i z e d   d a s h e s        t h e y   c a n   b e   u s e f u l .   N o w   w e &rsquo; r e   d o n e ! 





 Y o u   m i g h t   n e e d   2 - - 3   d i f f e r e n t - s i z e d   d a s h e s - - - t h e y   c a n   b e   u s e f u l .   N o w   w e &rsquo; r e   d o n e !</p>
<div id="footer">
<div id="footer-text">
Page generated 2017-06-25 02:43:36 Eastern Daylight Time, by <a href="http://jemdoc.jaboc.net/">jemdoc</a>.
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

As I open the file in a text editor, it's like this:

[image]

and finally here is what the browser shows:

[image]

Seemingly, `jemdoc.css` has not been applied to the file at all.

Any help?...